# Java: Group list elements by type

Tags: java, optimization

Currently I'm using Java 6. For... for reasons. Now I want to group all elements in a list by their date, so I don't have multiple entries for each date.

Let's say I have a list that structurally looks like this:

```
+==============+=============+
| dateHappened |  pottyUses  |
+==============+=============+
| 10/09/2015   |     255     |
+--------------+-------------+
| 10/09/2015   |     256     |
+--------------+-------------+
| 10/09/2015   |     254     |
+--------------+-------------+
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
+==============+=============+
| dateHappened |  pottyUses  |
+==============+=============+
| 10/09/2015   |     765     |
+--------------+-------------+
```

The list code looks like this:

```
public class PottyCollection implements Comparable<PottyCollection>
{
    public PottyCollection(final Date dateHappened, final int pottyUses)
    {
        this.dateHappened = dateHappened;
        this.pottyUses = pottyUses;
    }
    final public Date dateHappened;
    final public int pottyUses;
}
```

So far, I've been creating two separate instances of `PottyCollection`. The first one (full) gets sorted by `Date` using `Collections.Sort()`. The second one (empty) then loops through the entire list, and for each date we've found, it will increment  `newPottyUses` by that date. When a new date is found, it will insert all of that data into the new list, and reset `newPottyUses`, then continue the loop until it's finished.

For a couple items, this is fine. For a large list with a lot of different types, it's getting to the point where it isn't very maintainable. I can't help but feel like there's some wheel reinventing going on here.

Is there a better way? Both Java 6, and 8 solutions would be appreciated, but for now, only 6 can be checked.

Comment: Sadly, only 6. :( However, I would be very open to seeing both solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Map:

```
Map<Date, PottyCollection> map = new HashMap<>();
for (PottyCollection pc : originalList) {
    PottyCollection existing = map.get(pc.dateHappened);
    if (existing == null) {
        map.put(pc.dateHappened, pc);
    }
    else {
        map.put(pc.dateHappened, new PottyCollection(pc.dateHappened, pc.pottyUses + existing.pottyUses));
    }
}
Collection<PottyCollection> reduced = map.values();
```

Comment: Just a note: since I am using Java 6, you'll have to change new `HashMap<>();` to this: `new HashMap<Date, PottyCollection>();`. Change that, and the answer is yours.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a `TreeMap<K,V>` instead of a `List<E>`?

The elements of a `TreeMap` are naturally ordered according to their key. Furthermore, by overwritting the `put` method, you can detect whether a certain date is already present.

**Code sample:**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class PottyCollection extends TreeMap<Date, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer put(Date key, Integer value) {
        if (containsKey(key)) {
            return super.put(key, get(key) + value);
        } else
            return super.put(key, value);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PottyCollection collection = new PottyCollection();
        collection.put(new Date(0), 100);
        collection.put(new Date(1), 55);
        collection.put(new Date(0), 55);

        System.out.println(collection);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970=155, Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970=55}
```

Comment: Why would I use a `TreeMap` over a `Map`? Which one would be better for this particular scenario?

Comment: @EduardoScissaro, a `TreeMap`'s elements are ordered using the `compareTo` method of the key elements (here the dates). Therefore, all elements in the `TreeMap` are automatically ordered by the date. I thought this was important since the OP's `PottyCollection` implements the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Great. Now what if I have multiple data types in this list? `extends TreeMap<Date, Integer, String, String, Long, Integer>`...? Obviously that won't work since it's a `K,V`, but how would I use this with multiple data types? Will `collection.put(new Date(0), 0, "", "", 22000, 0)` work for this?

Comment: Extending TreeMap is a very bad idea. The put() method doesn't respect the Map contract. Using putAll() instead of put() has a good chance of breaking the code, etc. Favor delegation over inheritance.